# How to remove empty objects in an array by passing it to a function - javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

Hi Here i am having a object that is returned from api.

```
let ApiData1 = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 10,
                "stateId": 10,
                "name": "Tamil Nadu",
                "code": "TN"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 11,
                "stateId": 11,
                "name": "Karnataka",
                "code": "KA"
            }
        },
        null,
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 12,
                "stateId": 12,
                "name": "Pondicherry",
                "code": "PY"
            }
        },
        null,
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 1,
                "stateId": 1,
                "name": "Delhi",
                "code": "DL"
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

In this data , in `ApiData1.features` . there are some null values retuned . I need to remove this null values and has to return like this.

**OutPut**

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 10,
                "stateId": 10,
                "name": "Tamil Nadu",
                "code": "TN"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 11,
                "stateId": 11,
                "name": "Karnataka",
                "code": "KA"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 12,
                "stateId": 12,
                "name": "Pondicherry",
                "code": "PY"
            }
        },
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 1,
                "stateId": 1,
                "name": "Delhi",
                "code": "DL"
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

is anyway to achieve this by passing this ApiData into a function and return like this. Could u please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this related to the question you asked 32 minutes ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61965838/modify-and-return-object-in-javascript

Comment: kind of, but it is not same.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Might take a look at the `Array.filter` method

Comment: `ApiData1.features = ApiData1.features.filter(o => o)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this , it should help get rid of nulls

```
ApiData1.features = ApiData1.features.filter(ob => ob !==null)
```

Comment: Are you sure you can assign the value like this? Will ```ApiData1.features``` be recognized as a valid variable name?

Comment: Yes, you can . We dont want to change the full ApiData1 , we need to filter out the values from the features array only.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan `ApiData1.features` is NOT a variable name, `features` is a property of the object in variable `ApiData1`

Comment: @JaromandaX, Thanks for mentioning it, I can understand now that property value is alone getting changed.. My bad understanding..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ES6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the null data, here is a working snippet:

```js
let ApiData1 = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 10,
                "stateId": 10,
                "name": "Tamil Nadu",
                "code": "TN"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 11,
                "stateId": 11,
                "name": "Karnataka",
                "code": "KA"
            }
        },
        null,
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 12,
                "stateId": 12,
                "name": "Pondicherry",
                "code": "PY"
            }
        },
        null,
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 1,
                "stateId": 1,
                "name": "Delhi",
                "code": "DL"
            }
        }

    ]
}

let newData = {
  ...ApiData1,
  features: ApiData1.features.filter((el) => el)
}

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Added flavor of **Imperative style** of coding.

- Used `forEach` loop
- In JS object/Arrays are pass by ref.
- Updates `ApiData1` features data using [...spreadOperator]

```
  var ApiData1 = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 10,
                "stateId": 10,
                "name": "Tamil Nadu",
                "code": "TN"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 11,
                "stateId": 11,
                "name": "Karnataka",
                "code": "KA"
            }
        },
        null,
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 12,
                "stateId": 12,
                "name": "Pondicherry",
                "code": "PY"
            }
        },
        null,
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 1,
                "stateId": 1,
                "name": "Delhi",
                "code": "DL"
            }
        }

    ]
};


var features =[];
ApiData1.features.forEach(feature => feature ? features.push(feature): null);
ApiData1['features'] = [...features];
console.log(ApiData1);
```